# Writing to Cycling Control Point to get Sampling Rate

Tags: matlab, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to develop a matlab code that gets Cycling power from a BLE power pedal device. I am successful in getting the power, but i want to understand what is the sampling rate of this. I looked up CPP service document and found that i have to write "0x20", to the Cycling Power Control Point service. But when I try to do this I get an error stating
"Operation failed because there was an unknown error."

What am I doing wrong? I apologize I am new to this bluetooth stuff.

```
ble("ASSIOMA34661U")
c = characteristic(ans,"1818","2A66")
write(c,"0x20"))
```

Tried this code but it showed an error statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Matlab, but 0x20 is a response code sent by the device.

You should take a look at this document which describes a test procedure for the cycling power service: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/4/CPS.TS.1.1.2.pdf

You are probably looking for 0x0D to configure the data you want to receive, and the device should then reply with a 0x20 response code.